# Is there any contact information on the SD card?

Tags: contacts, external-sd

I found an sd card that was definitely in someone's android phone. Is there any file within the card that would have it's owner's info, so that I might contact them somehow and return what they've lost? Just going out of my way to be a good samaritan here....

Comment: wow, thanks for the quick reply! My first thought was to just keep it, but when I looked inside (just over the surface) there seemed to be a lot of information, so I kinda felt bad for the guy who lost it. I left my # @ the place I found it in, so if someone comes looking for it, they'll find it. If not, I'll reformat it after a week or so.

Comment: If you used skype not some long time time, it saved all contact data into SD card...

Answer (score 4):

Not by default, no. You can export contacts to the sdcard, but that would only contain "the owner" if they have themselves in their contacts. But you would also probably have no clue which one is them.

While it is a grand gesture on your part, I think you are the new owner of a used sdcard.

Comment: I agree.  Google most likely went out of their way to *not* store any user identifiable information on removable storage for security and privacy concerns.  Although you might find some left over app data or cache, I'd be very surprised if it contained anything useful for tracking down the previous owner.

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan said, you can export the contacts to the card, if you were to put the card in your phone you could potentially look at the contacts and maybe they have someone in their phone listed as  "mom" or "girlfriend" or something that would help you identify them.

Comment: I have a BB, so.....

Comment: the exported file would already be on there probably saved as "contacts.csv" or something of the sort. if it's not there, then they never exported and you would be spending more time then the cost of a new sdcard trying to find data to identify the owner.

Comment: I assumed you had an Android phone, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Android by default doesn't save any personally identifiable info to the SD card, the system backs up/syncs important data to the web, not the SD card but there may be a chance that an app has saved something useful to there . Most apps store their main settings (which is where things like login names/email addresses would be) in the phone's internal memory, only using the SD card for storing larger files and cached data.

The most obvious would be to look for pictures, but depending how they use their camera, etc that may not be any help. They may have files with identifiable info in the `Download` folder, from saved email attachments, web pages, etc.

For some common apps that may be likely:

If they've used an app like [LifeSaver](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.textuality.lifesaver2) to back up their call log or message log to their SD card, then you could open that and look for frequently contacted numbers. This would be a text file in a folder called `LifeSever` or `LifeSaver-F` that can be opened in Notepad.

If they use [Dropbox](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dropbox.android), they may have saved files with useful info into the `Dropbox` folder.

Possibly the photos could be helpful

Comment: I don't think I saw any folders under that. I did go through a few pics, and if a magically bump into the guy I'd probably recognize him.... thanx again

Answer (score 1):

I just found someone using Spotify data on the SD card at path:

/Android/data/com.spotify.music/files/spotifycache/Users/<10-digit-user-id>-user

Then check the URL:
https://open.spotify.com/user/<10-digit-user-id>

That was their Spotify account.